# Melhor maneira de percorrer um HashSet

Tags: java, collection, hashset

Estou acostumado a programar em PHP e agora estou estudando Java, e a API de Collections é algo novo e bem interessante pra mim.

Pesquisei na internet e facilmente encontrei várias maneiras de percorrer um HashSet, como:

- Java 8 forEach e lambda expression.
- iterator().
- iterator() e Java 8 método forEachRemaining().
- simples for-each loop.

Mas, qual é a melhor maneira de percorrer? Ou qual é a diferença entre as várias opções e qual eu devo usar em casos diferentes?

Comment: Depende de muita coisa. Muitas vezes melhor um simples `for-each`, mas tem casos em que você necessita do `iterator`. O  método `.forEach` eu não vejo muita necessidade de usar no caso geral, mas fica com uma aparência mais funcional de ser. Se você receber um `Consumer` para fazer a iteração, então nesse caso o método `.forEach` é o melhor. Eu não conheço o `.forEachRemaining`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalmente eu recomendaria ir pelo laço `for-each` tradicional. Ele resolve boa parte do que você normalmente deseja quando percorre uma coleção.

Claro, existem algumas exceções. E também existe motivos de convenção para tratar de outro jeito (chegarei lá).

### `for-each`

Os casos mais triviais de se iterar uma coleção (qualquer que seja) é simplesmente tratar cada elemento da coleção, sem alterar a coleção propriamente dita. E normalmente você guarda o resultado da avaliação em uma variável *externa* ao laço, para trabalhar com esse resultado depois. Para esses casos, a maior simplicidade do `for-each` é suficiente.

Além disso, você tem todas as vantagens de controle de fluxo de um laço convencional:

- `continue` para evitar processamentos desnecessários (e níveis extras de indentação em blocos `if`)
- `break` para parar a execução do laço
- `return` para quando já se tem o resultado desejado e não há mais porque continuar processando

### `Iterator`

O laço através do `Iterator` só é estritamente necessário se for desejado alterar a coleção *durante* a iteração. Normalmente, em um `Set`, eu só vi sendo usado para remover elementos da coleção. Em um `List` eu já vi sendo usado para substituir elementos.

> Como o laço `for-each` usa o `Iterator` por baixo, porém escondendo todo esse arcabouço de código em uma sintaxe doce e fofa, se você não for usar os métodos próprios do `Iterator`, então é melhor usar o `for-each`.

Mesmo assim, mesmo sendo o `Iterator` o mais adequado para esses casos, a equipe aqui no trabalho prefere contornar o seu uso. Então (na era de Java 7 + Retrolambda, sem direito a `Streams` do Java 8), para remover elementos, detectamos todos os elementos que precisam ser removidos e guardamos numa lista de ações aquilo que desejávamos:

```
Set<Elemento> conjunto = ...;
ArrayList<Runnable> acoesRemocaoPostuma = new ArrayList<>();

for (Elemento e: conjunto) {
  if (devoRemover(e)) {
    acoesRemocaoPostuma.add(() -> conjunto.remove(e));
  }
}
for (Runnable acao: acoesRemocaoPostuma) {
  acao.run();
}
```

Além disso, você tem todas as vantagens de controle de fluxo de um laço convencional:

- `continue` para evitar processamentos desnecessários (e níveis extras de indentação em blocos `if`)
- `break` para parar a execução do laço
- `return` para quando já se tem o resultado desejado

### `Iterator.forEachRemaining`

Nunca usei e desconheço totalmente seu uso, fico devendo para atualizar essa resposta no futuro.

### Método `.forEach`

Normalmente eu só vejo vantagem prática em usar esse método em 2 cenários:

1. você recebe um `Consumer` como parâmetro
2. você só precisa chamar uma função para avaliar os elementos

Por exemplo, executar todas as ações em uma lista de `Runnable` ficaria assim:

```
List<Runnable> listaAcoes = ...;
listaAcoes.forEach(Runnable::run);
```

Se eu precisar, para cada elemento do conjunto, chamar uma função chamada de `sincroniza` passando como parâmetro uma string que representa o destino:

```
String destino = ...;
Set<Elemento> conjunto = ...;

conjunto.forEach(e -> sincroniza(destino, e));
```

O equivalente via laço desse código é um pouco mais verboso:

```
String destino = ...;
Set<Elemento> conjunto = ...;

for (Elemento e: conjunto) {
  sincroniza(destino, e);
}
```

Além disso, também tem uma vantagem de *convenção* ao se iterar desse jeito. Em uma equipe formada por pessoas jovens e sem muita experiência, o uso de laços "incentiva" alterar valores de variáveis locais, porém externas à iteração específica. E, bem... em um código legado que não foi estruturado corretamente enquanto crescia, isso pode gerar efeitos colaterais não desejados e esconder bugs. Forçando a sempre usar funções lambda, essas alterações não ocorrem, são proibidas pela linguagem.

Uma desvantagem de se usar essa estrutura para se iterar é que ela não oferece suporte para controle do laço. Você não pode, diretamente, ignorar elementos com `continue`, nem também parar o processamento com um `break` e muito  menos usar um `return` para avisar ao chamador que encontrou o que se desejava.

### usando `Stream`s para substituir laços

Uma outra maneira de se iterar em elementos é usar uma `stream` do Java 8. E isso tem sido visto com muito bons olhos pela minha equipe, mas não é unânime. Usar `stream` implica em um pensamento menos imperativo/estruturado e mais declarativo/funcional, e programação funcional tem tanto fãs (tipo eu) quanto detratores, sendo pessoas em cima do muro espécimes raros que precisam ser estudados.

Com as construções de `stream`, você consegue simular boa parte do controle de fluxo que você fazia com o laço.

Contar apenas as strings que começam com "marm"? Filtre e conte:

```
conjuntoDeStringa.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("marm")).count();
```

Retornar algum `Elemento` que esteja ativo? Retornando `null` caso não encontre?

```
conjunto.stream().filter(Elemento::estahAtivo).findAny().orElse(null);
```

Concatenar todos os objetos, convertendo-os com `toString` e separando-os com `;`?

```
conjunto.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
```

Descobrir qual dos elementos `Elemento` retorna o maior inteiro em `valorResgate`? Retornando -1 no caso de conjunto vazio?

```
conjunto.stream().mapToInt(Elemento::valorResgate).max().orElse(-1);
```

Aqui onde trabalho trabalhamos muito com `BigDecimal`, e é muito fácil o programador errar como somar os elementos de uma lista. Então, preferimos usar `stream` para resolver isso e evitar que passem na revisão esses bugs:

```
itens.stream().map(Item::getVrItem).collect(BigDecimalUtils.coletorSoma());
```

> Devido a idiossincrasias do nosso sistema funcionar ao mesmo tempo em Java, JavaScript (transformado de Java pelo GWT) e TotalCross, precisamos usar um wrapper de `BigDecimal` próprio, já que o TotalCross não suportava na época com plenitude `java.math.BigDecimal`.

De modo geral, a experiência aqui no trabalho indica que o laço `for-each` é mais fácil, porém usar `streams` se mostrou menos problemático e exigiu um nível maior de abstração da equipe, de certo modo fazendo-os pensarem mais e melhor o que querem fazer.

Comment: Excelente resposta e muito bem detalhada, muito obrigado!