# Verificar existência de objeto em loop for

Tags: java, loop

Estou executando um loop que deve iterar 30 vezes que corresponde aos dias do mês... e esse loop é iterado com dados vindo do banco que trás os dias cadastrados de itens (exemplo: dia 6 compra de borracha), só que durante esses dias pode não haver compras e estou querendo preencher como 0, os dias que não há compras, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
List<ProducaoDiaria> producaoDiariaDTO = producaoDiariaSS.getDados(query);

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {    
ProdDiaria prodDiaria = new ProdDiaria();

if (producaoDiariaDTO.get(i) != null && !producaoDiariaDTO.get(i).equals("")) {
        if (producaoDiariaDTO.get(i).getDia() == i) {
            prodDiaria.setCdConvenio(Integer.toString(producaoDiariaDTO.get(i).getCdConvenio()));
            prodDiaria.setDia(Integer.toString(producaoDiariaDTO.get(i).getDia()));
            prodDiaria.setNmConvenio(producaoDiariaDTO.get(i).getNmConvenio());
            prodDiaria.setValor(producaoDiariaDTO.get(i).getValor().toString());
        } 
} else {
       prodDiaria.setCdConvenio("");
       prodDiaria.setDia(Integer.toString(i + 1));
       prodDiaria.setNmConvenio("");
       prodDiaria.setValor("");
}
}
```

Só que como há apenas um elemento logo após a primeira iteração ele me retorna

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`

O resultado esperado é:

Dia 1 : 0 `(N existe dado)`

Dia 2 : 0 `(N existe dado)`

Dia 3 : 6

Dia 4 : 0 `(N existe dado)`

Comment: Esse erro dá porque a lista só tem um elemento. Quando ela executa na primeira iteração `i == 0`, e, então, dá tudo certo para essa lista. Porém, na segunda iteração (que é forçosamente até o índice `30` ignorando o tamanho da lista), quando `i == 1`, dar um `producaoDiariaDTO.get(1)` dá esse `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado entendi por que o erro ocorre, queria uma solução na verdade :/

Comment: Sobre modos de se iterar uma coleção: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343925/64969 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/255193/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado nas duas situação o for se limita a quantidade de itens que o Array tem, e eu quero que tendo ou não 30, ele execute e preencha com 0 os q n tem

Comment: A lógica desse código está comprometida, você presume que `producaoDiariaSS.getDados(query);` irá retornar uma lista cujo os índices estarão emparelhados com as datas contidas nos respectivos elementos. Isso não vai acontecer, você vai encontrar situações onde o primeiro elemento(índice 0) é datado no dia cinco, o segundo elemento(índice 1) é datado no dia quinze. esse trecho `if (producaoDiariaDTO.get(i).getDia() == i)` reforça a necessidade do empalhamento. A saída para você é modificar `producaoDiariaSS.getDados()` para que entregue uma lista já preenchida com as datas ausentes.

Comment: Ou vc enche a lista de null's ou então usa outra estrutura de dados. Provavelmente um map é melhor para esse caso

Comment: Como você está usando uma List, não é melhor fazer um foreach,  e antes verificar quantos elementos essa lista tem? assim vc já tem previsibilidade da quantidade de dias.

Answer (score 1):

O erro indica que o seu List tem tamanho 1, e no seu laço for ele percorre 30 vezes,
ou seja, só tem 1 registro no seu array, logo no seu primeiro `if` `producaoDiariaDTO.get(i) != null` voce esta verificando se o valor é nulo, como o seu `producaoDiariaDTO.size()==1`, ele recupera o tamanho 2 que não existe, logo
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Acredito que isso já resolva 
`if (producaoDiariaDTO.size() >= i && producaoDiariaDTO.get(i) != null && !producaoDiariaDTO.get(i).equals("")) { 
///resto do codigo
}`